# Does the usage guidance for the [closed-questions] tag on this Meta need to be updated?

Tags: discussion, tags, closed-questions, meta, tag-wiki

The usage guidance for [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions) says:

> This tag is for posts looking to raise meta discussions about *specific closed questions*, as well as for questions about the concept of a closed question in general.

In practice, one of the ways we are using this tag is for meta discussion about whether a particular question should be closed. The tag description says it is for discussing *closed* questions, but oftentimes the attendant main-site question is open when we start the meta discussion, and the results determine if the question remains open or gets closed.

Should we update the usage guidance to account for this? I found myself confused when trying to determine which tag to add to a meta discussion, since the question I was asking about was open, but the tag says it's for closed questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes. We should update it.

We also use the tag to discuss the closure of questions in contentious cases or to double-check one's reason for a closure of a question that they think might need closure.

I think this would do the job:

> This tag is for posts looking to raise meta discussions about specific
> closed questions or the closure of a specific question, as well as for
> questions about the concept of a closed question in general.

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated the description, per your suggestion.